# How to rename selected objects except active object?

Tags: objects

I wrote a script to rename selected objects except for active objects but it's renaming the active object.

I want the operator button to disable/inactive when the objects are not selected.

Here is my script:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
ao = C.object
name = ao.name
so = C.selected_objects
ao.select_set(False)
for obj in so:
    C.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.name = "SM_"+name
```

[image]

Comment: You are defining `so` before removing the active object

Comment: This. Invert lines 6 and 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check if it is the selected object and ignore it

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
ao = C.object
for obj in C.selected_objects:
    if obj != ao:
        obj.name = "SM_"+ao.name
```